# How to override other CSS styles?

Tags: css, font-size

I'm using this Chrome extension called Stylus that allows me to use custom CSS sheets for any website. I use this to make the font larger for easier reading. Here is my code:

```css
body {
    font-size: large;
}
```

Unfortunately, this gets inconsistent results. On some websites it makes the font larger as desired, but on many websites it has no effect, or worse it only affects the font size in the sidebar. Is there a way I can my code take priority? I tried using `!important` but that still had inconsistent results.

Comment: Increase the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with `*` it means all so the `font-size` will be applied to all but in that case of style is not being applied to all websites may be is the problem of an extension or try to update your extension and activate it.
and the following is the code of CSS to apply the same `font-size` to all elements in the website

```
*{
    font-size: large;
}
```

and you should know that there are many websites reject those extensions running on them because of the security issues

Comment: Thanks! It seems that `*` has highest specificity, even higher than `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

actually creating any style property, below another property will actually override it,

example:

```
body{
          font-size: large;
          color: white;
     }

      /*Now creating a same style property will override the above style in the  particular element*/  

 h1{
     font-size: small;
     color: grey
  }
     /*The styles from the body will be overridden for the h1 tags*/

     /*For global */

 *{
       color: pink
  }

     /*This above block will override the styles declared for body*/
```

All of this works because CSS will follow a top down approach so the styles declared in the bottom will be considered while rendering,

Other method is to use Inline CSS, they will override all styles.

Comment: This doesn't really help because I can't control whether my style sheet goes above or below the website's style sheet. Using `*` seemed to work though.